# Nestjs, inject JwtService in controller

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm trying to use the `JwtService` from nestjs to decode an access_token in a controller, but I don't know how to inject this service in the constructor.

Here is my code:

```
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { Controller, Get, Post, Body, Req } from '@nestjs/common';
@Controller('event')
export class EventController {
    constructor(
        private readonly jwtService: JwtService) {}

@Get('/questions')
    async getQuestionsAsync(): Promise<Question[]> {
    const decodedToken = this.jwtService.decode(accessToken);
    ...
}
```

I'm getting this error:

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the EventController (EventService, ?). Please make sure that the argument JwtService at index [1] is available in the EventModule context.

I have already tried to add `@Inject(JwtService)` as an attribute to the private variable, but the error is the same.

So, how do I correctly inject the JwtService in the controller ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that `JwtModule` is added to the `imports` array of the `EventModule` **or** if it is configured elsewhere that it is exported from the module it is configured in and that the configuring module is imported into `EventModule`.

Comment: Currently, it's not imported in the event.module.ts, if I add the JwtModule in the imports array, I start to get the error saying "Please make sure that the argument JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS is available in the JwtModule context"
I just want to use the JwtService to decode a token (so I don't need to install the jsonwebtoken)

Comment: Did you import it with its registration options? `JwtModule.register()`. You'll need to make sure to pass the jwt secret via the options, otherwise it doesn't really have a way to verify the token, and while decoding doesn't need verification, it's still a good practice

Comment: The key was the .register (I was missing that)!
Thanks Jay